# vuejs3 routing issue, it is not display router-view or i make mistake somewhere?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router, router

I'm currently working on a Vue.js project and facing challenges with navigation. Specifically, I'm facing difficulties navigating from the ProjectTypeSection to the InteriorDesignView and ExteriorDesignView pages. Maybe I use routes in wrong way maybe I use  in wrong place

I've tried various solutions, but unfortunately, I couldn't identify the root cause. I've refrained from pasting the entire code here for clarity reasons, but I'll mention specific components that may be contributing to the problem: ProjectTypeSection, ProjectsView, InteriorDesignView, ExteriorDesignView, and the routes folder.

Here slices of my code

routes/pagesRoutes.js

```
    import ProjectsView from '@/views/ProjectsView.vue'
    import ServicesView from '@/views/ServicesView.vue'
    import AboutUsView from '@/views/AboutUsView.vue'
    import JoinUsView from '@/views/JoinUsView.vue'
    import ContactUsView from '@/views/ContactUsView.vue'
    import InteriorDesignView from '@/views/InteriorDesignView.vue'
    import ArchitectureView from '@/views/ExteriorDesignView.vue'
    
    export const pagesRoutes = [
      {
        path: '/projects',
        name: 'projects',
        component: ProjectsView,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'interior-design',
            name: 'interiorDesign',
            component: InteriorDesignView
          },
          {
            path: 'exterior-design',
            name: 'exteriorDesign',
            component: ArchitectureView
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '/services',
        name: 'services',
        component: ServicesView
      },
      {
        path: '/about_us',
        name: 'aboutUs',
        component: AboutUsView
      },
      {
        path: '/join_us',
        name: 'joinUs',
        component: JoinUsView
      },
      {
        path: '/contact_us',
        name: 'contact',
        component: ContactUsView
      }
    ]
```

routes/index.js

```
        import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
        import { pagesRoutes } from '@/router/pagesRoutes.js'
        import HomeView from '@/views/HomeView.vue'
        import store from '@/store/store.js'
        
        let routes = [
          {
            path: '/',
            name: "home",
            component: HomeView
          },
          ...pagesRoutes
        ]
        
        
        const router = createRouter({
          history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
          routes
        })
        
        router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            store.commit("closeMobileMenu");
            next()
        })
        export default router
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <AppHeader/>
  <div
    class="w-0 h-[54rem] bg-black opacity-70 absolute top-0 left-0 z-10 xl:hidden lg:hidden transition-all overflow-hidden"
    :class="{ 'w-1/2' : $store.state.isOpen }">
    <AppMobileMenu/>
  </div>
    <router-view/>
  <AppFooter/>
</template>

<script setup>
import AppHeader from '@/components/AppHeader.vue'
import AppFooter from '@/components/AppFooter.vue'
import AppMobileMenu from '@/components/AppMobileMenu.vue'
</script>
```

ProjectTypeSection.vue from where the routing should navigate to ExteriorDesignView.vue and to InteriorDesignView.vue

```
<template>
  <section class="w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center mt-[9rem]">
    <span class="text-5xl uppercase">Projects</span>
    <div class="w-full flex justify-center items-center mt-40">
      <div class="w-full flex max-lg:flex-col justify-around items-center gap-14">
        <router-link
          class="w-full flex max-sm:justify-center max-md:justify-center max-lg:justify-center"
          v-for="item of combineData"
          :key="item.id"
          :to="item.route"
        >
          <div
            class="group w-full max-sm:w-full max-md:w-5/6 max-lg:w-11/12 h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-start gap-8 relative">
            <img
              class="grayscale w-full h-full object-cover group-hover:grayscale-0 transition-all"
              :src="item.image"
              :alt="item.alt"
            >
            <div
              class="w-full h-14 absolute bottom-0 left-0 z-10 text-pink-600 text-4xl bg-black opacity-70 pl-5 group-hover:text-white transition-all max-max-md:text-3xl flex items-center">
              {{ item.title }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import img from '../assets/testImagesFolder/12.jpg'
import img1 from '../assets/testImagesFolder/22..jpg'
import { pagesRoutes } from '@/router/pagesRoutes.js'

export default {
  setup() {
    const projectTypes = ref([
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Interior Design',
        image: img,
        alt: 'Interior photo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Exterior Design',
        image: img1,
        alt: 'Exterior photo'
      }
    ])

    const combineData = ref([])

    combineData.value = projectTypes.value.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        return {
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          image: item.image,
          alt: item.alt,
          route: `${pagesRoutes[0].path}/${pagesRoutes[0].children[0].path}`
        }
      } else if (index === 1) {
        return {
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          image: item.image,
          alt: item.alt,
          route: `${pagesRoutes[0].path}/${pagesRoutes[0].children[1].path}`
        }
      } else {
        return {
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          image: item.image,
          alt: item.alt,
          route: pagesRoutes[index].path
        }
      }
    })

    return { combineData }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Reposting the same question won't do any good. It has the same problems, this comment is still applicable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906349/how-can-i-correct-my-vuejs3-routing-it-is-not-display-router-view-or-i-make-mis#comment137349114_77906349 . You need to provide the relevant code in the question, this is required by SO rules. The question is supposed to contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make sense if (when) external link becomes unavailable, this is the way it can help not only you but future readers. In this case the problem is in routes.js

Comment: We want to help but as mentioned, it's improper to post links to code without also including any in your question. It only hurts your chances of an answer to post ALL your code because of how irrelevant **most** of the code is to the issue. It's important for yourself and others to be able to narrow down code to only what's relevant. It's a routing issue, so start with just posting the routes definition code, and the part of your component code where you initiate the routing, and any template code that has `<router-view />`. If we need more information we will ask!

Comment: Thank you, I added code here if you need more code, let me know

Comment: @DavidGyulinyan It's ok, thanks. I posted an answer You need `@` in order for the participants to receive a notification when there are several of them

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the way child routes are defined and used. As described in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes), the use of `component` in both parent and children routes presumes that `router-view` should exist in parent view (ProjectsView) in order for child views (InteriorDesignView, etc) to be rendered. This will result in ProjectsView and InteriorDesignView being rendered simultaneously in child route. If this is not the intention, route definition should be changed for ProjectsView and InteriorDesignView to be siblings:

```
  {
    path: '/projects',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'projects',
        component: ProjectsView,
      },
      {
        path: 'interior-design',
        name: 'interiorDesign',
        component: InteriorDesignView
      },
      {
        path: 'exterior-design',
        name: 'exteriorDesign',
        component: ArchitectureView
      }
    ]
  },
```